# How can I auto show country flag by languge code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual

I have a multilingual reactjs app and I want a flag icon to match with a language code when I change language, how to do it without having to upload each flag manually?

Comment: My bet would be to find some icon library of flags, and you set the icon name of the react component to be something like `<Icon name={country-${value}} />` (wrap the country value part in ` to make it a string, I can not in the comments or it messes with the formatting) and value might be english for example. There are many ways, but this is probably how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using some library, like [country-flag-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-flag-icons).

```
import * as Flags from 'country-flag-icons/react/3x2'

const Flag = Flags[value];
<Flag title={value} className="..."/>
```